# Can a function access its variables from previous invocation?

Tags: javascript

I am little bit confused with scopes and async functions. I understand its cores but I don't know if my problem has anything to do with it, or it is something else. A created a custom plugin:

```
(function ($) {
    createCalendar = options => {
        let elementID = randomString(32);

        endLoad = () =>{
            console.log(elementID);
            $(`#${elementID} .inner .loader`).css('display', 'none');
        }

        [...]

        getTimes(url)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(elementID);
                endLoad();
            })
    }
}(jQuery))
```

I invoke this function multiple times, because I create 4 or 5 calendars on a page. Each has a different ID. It's a 32 characters long string, so it's unlikely to be the same.
In the function I call the `getTimes` async function and in its callback function I want to remove the loader in the calendar - each calendar has its loader.
However, it only removes the last calendar's loader. If I try to log the element IDs, I get different results. The console.log in the `then` gives me correct value, so after rendering 5 calendars, and each has finished its loading, it logs 5 different strings. However just after this `console.log` has been executed comes the `endLoad` function, and it logs the same value - the last calendar's id for each calendar.
I thought because the async `getTimes` function is is a function which has it's own scope and the variable is defined with `let` it cannot access the createdID from previous invoke which is theoretically a different function. Or does the the JS considers it the same function because the same function was called multiple times? Or my problem is rooted in somewhere else?

Comment: You don't show where `createCalendar` is declared or how you later call it, but it looks to me like the issue is that it's in an outer scope and gets its value overwritten each time this IIFE is executed. So of course in that case it will only work with the ID that it got the last time it was overwritten.

Comment: the `createCalendar` is written in a different js file. In the html header it is added with the `<script>` tag. In the main .js file, I call this function multiple times.

Comment: OK, so it must be a global variable, which you're overwriting each time. I really don't understand why you're doing this. I think I need to see some more of your code - although I'm pretty certain the reason for the problem is as I've described.

Comment: Is it because you've declared `endLoad` as a global? Maybe declare it as `const endLoad`.

Comment: Good spot @Ouroborus, not sure how much I missed that.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, I didn't know that without keyword it is declared as a global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a variable without any keyword (`var`, `let`, `const`) it becomes global (same as doing `window.endLoad = …`). In your case, for every calendar the variable `endLoad` is overwriten. You need `endLoad` to be scoped to the arrow function.

```js
(function ($) {
    createCalendar = options => {
        let elementID = randomString(32);

        const endLoad = () =>{
            console.log(elementID);
            $(`#${elementID} .inner .loader`).css('display', 'none');
        }

        [...]

        getTimes(url)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(elementID);
                endLoad();
            })
    }
}(jQuery))
```